# JSON Data is not populating in Jqgrid

Tags: vb.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a method in my codebehind which will return the string jSON data. I have called that using AJAX call and i got the data. But i am unable to load the data to the Jqgrid.

```js
$("#tblFormData").jqGrid(
      {
          url:"Forms.aspx/ConvertDataTabletoString",
          datatype: 'jsonstring',
          colNames: ['Category_Id', 'Category'],
          colModel: [
                         { name: "Category_Id", index: "Category_Id", editable: false },
                         { name: "Category", index: "Category", editable: true }
          ],

          viewrecords: true,
          loadonce: true,
          gridview: true,
          autoencode: true,
         
          rowNum: 10000,



      });
```

Below is the data which i am getting if i call that using Ajax call

[
   {
      "Category_Id":1,
      "Category":"sss Forms"

},
   {
      "Category_Id":1,
      "Category":"sss Forms"
   }
   ]

So if i assign this to a variable and then assign it to a gridview it is working fine. But it is not directly.

```js
 var subgridData1 = [
    {
        "Category_Id": 1,
        "Category": "sss Forms"
    },
    {
        "Category_Id": 1,
        "Category": "sss Forms"
    },
   
   ]

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Forms.aspx/ConvertDataTabletoString",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {

        debugger;
        //var formJsondata = msg.d;
        $("#tblFormData").jqGrid(
       {
           data: subgridData1,
           datatype:'json',
           colNames: ['Category_Id', 'Category'],
           colModel: [
                          { name: "Category_Id", index: "Category_Id", editable: false },
                          { name: "Category", index: "Category", editable: true }
           ],
          
           viewrecords: true,
           loadonce: true

         
       });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What data exactly will be returned from the server? (**you could append your question with the test data**, you could use Developer Tools of Internet Explorer/Chrome/Firefox to trace the exact HTTP traffic). You makes an Ajax call using `dataType: "json"` and `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` option. Do you really still need to call `JSON.stringify` (see the line `var mydata = JSON.stringify(msg);`). If it's required that you makes unneeded conversion of JSON to JSON on the server side. Typical error is **unneeded** call of `JavaScriptSerializer` or `DataContractJsonSerializer` on the server side and returning string instead of object from web method. You should remove the call on the server side and you will have `msg` already as the object.

The code inside of `success` seems be wrong too. You don't specified `datatype` parameter, so the default value `"xml"` will be used. The parameter `datastr` will be ignored and the request to `url: ""` will be done. The XML format are expected from the server. *Depend on the format of the data returned from the server* you need use `datatype: "jsonstring"` or `datatype: "local"`.

Alternatively you can add `url: "Forms.aspx/ConvertDataTabletoString"` and use `datatype: "json"` with `loadonce: true` option to the list of jqGrid options. No separate Ajax call will be needed.

In way way you should add `gridview: true`, `autoencode: true` option to jqGrid. You should add the pager option (or `toppager: true`) or to use `rowNum: 10000` if you don't want to use local paging. You should consider to add `key: true` property to `Category_Id` column.

Comment: Hi Oleg Thanks you very much for your quick reply. i have modified the code as you said. In another way i can get the data and show it into the page by locally assigned data. But the same data i am not able to assign it to grid. i will post you the code with data

Comment: I have modified my question now. could you able to look into it now. @Oleg

Comment: @Parthhu: You still use wrong options of jqGrid. `datatype:'json'` means the **jqGrid have to make Ajax request for you to URL specified by `url` option**. `data` option will be ignored in the case. So you have to use `datatype: "local"` if you want to specify input data in `data` option. After that you should see the data in the grid. `loadonce: true` option have sense only in case of usage  `datatype:'json'`. I strictly recommend you to include other options which I described in my answer at least the following: `gridview: true, autoencode: true, rowNum: 10000`

Comment: Thanks @Oleg. It is all working fine. I have converted the JSON data to Array and then i bind the data to the Jqgrid.          var parsed = JSON.parse(formJsondata);

        var arr = [];

        for (var x in parsed) {
            arr.push(parsed[x]);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
            $("#tblFormData").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, arr[i]);
        }

Comment: @Parthhu: You are welcome! Without an example of `parsed` data it's difficult to change the above code, but you should **never** user `addRowData` in the loop. It's the **slowest way to fill the grid which I know**. You should get parameters of jqGrid by `var p = $("#tblFormData").jqGrid("getGridParam");`, replace `p.data` to new array of items (something like `p.data = arr;`) and set `p._index = {};` After all you should trigger reloadGrid: `$("#tblFormData").trigger("reloadGrid");` to refresh the grid with new assigned data. It makes sorting and paging of data additionally.